# Select several rows into several variables - Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one select statement that returns a query like this:

```
SELECT value FROM dummy WHERE condition = 1;

    ROW | value
   -----|-----
    1   | val1
    2   | val2
    3   | val3
    4   | val4
```

I have 4 variables

```
r1, r2, r3, r4
```

What is the cleanest way to assign those variables the values of my query?
Can I use a SELECT INTO statement?

Comment: Define the array x and fill it using select ... bulk collect into x.

Comment: You had better add `and rownum < 5` to your where clause.  I hope this is concept code and not production code.

Comment: It's not going anywhere near a productive system, but thanks for your concern and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
SELECT p_v1 = MAX(CASE WHEN row = 1 THEN value end),
       p_v2 = MAX(CASE WHEN row = 2 THEN value end),
       p_v3 = MAX(CASE WHEN row = 3 THEN value end),
       p_v4 = MAX(CASE WHEN row = 4 THEN value end)
FROM dummy
WHERE condition = 1;
```

This is an aggregation query that returns one row.  If a particular row is missing, then the value will be `NULL`.

Comment: I had to replace row with rownum for this to work, but it's a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can uae `PIVOT` as following;

```
Select v1, v2, v3, v4 
       Into val1, val2, val3, val4
From (SELECT value FROM dummy WHERE condition = 1)
Pivot
(Max(value) for row in (1 as v1, 2 as v2, 3 as v3, 4 as v4))
```

Cheers!!